# Como soluciono "Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object"?

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos

La verdad estoy empezando en esto de php y no tengo ni idea de por que este error, trato de desplegar los valores de mi base de datos en una tabla y me sale esto

Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Panel\index.php on line 36

```html
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
      // Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      } 
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM mensajes";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["nombre"] . "</td><td>"
    . $row["email"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    } else { echo "0 results"; }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: $conn->query te devuelve false si falla. Fijate si es false antes de buscar los resultados.

Answer (score 2):

Te propongo este código, el cual controlará en todo momento cualquier eventualidad que ocurra, informando adecuadamente de la misma.

Como ya algunos han señalado, conviene que pongas como último parámetro de la conexión el nombre de la base de datos.

He establecido un control para capturar posibles fallos de la consulta.

También, he cambiado el estilo de la conexión, usando en todo el código el estilo orientado a objetos. En tu código hay mezcla de estilos, lo cual, aunque no es motivo de error no es recomendable porque crea un código confuso y difícil de analizar. El estilo orientado a objetos es más claro, moderno e intuitivo, por lo que es preferido sobre el estilo procedural.

En el código uso una variable `$output` que va recogiendo durante el flujo los resultados. Al final imprimo esa variable con el resultado que haya obtenido. Por cierto, tampoco estabas abriendo la etiqueta `<table>` antes del `while`.

Esta es mi propuesta. Espero que te sea útil:

```
<?php
    if ( !$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "PON-AQUI-NOMBRE-BASE-DE-DATOS") ){
        $output="Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error;      
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mensajes";
        if ( $result = $conn->query($sql) ){
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $output="<table>";
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $output.= "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["nombre"] . "</td><td>". $row["email"]. "</td></tr>";
                }
                $output.="</table>";
            } else { 
                $output= "0 results"; 
            }
        } else {
                $output="Error en la consulta: ".$conn->error;
        }
        $conn->close();
    }
    echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Agrega una condicion para el caso en que la consulta te devuelve vació:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
      // Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      } 
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM mensajes";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0) { //Agregada condicion
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["nombre"] . "</td><td>"
    . $row["email"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    } else { echo "0 results"; }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mira lo Posible es que tengas mal tu conexion o los campos de la tabla, lo he probado en una base de datos propia y me arroja los elementos, escuestion de que revices tu codigo y verifica si los datos son correcto, en este caso veo que no le dices a que base de datos va hacer tu consulta.

en mi caso se llama *citas.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "*******","citas");
```

En los asteriscos seria la contraseña del usuario que usa el gestor de la base de datos.

este es mi codigo:

```
    <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "*******","citas");
      // Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      } 
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM Pacientes";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["pacIdentificacion"]. "</td><td>" . $row["pacNombres"] . "</td><td>"
    . $row["pacApellidos"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    } 
    else { 
      echo "0 results"; 
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Espero te sirva: saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas seguro es que tu consulta `SELECT * FROM mensajes` fallo por lo que devuelve **false**  mira aqui en este enlace [mysqli.query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) . Como esta devolviendo *false* cuando haces `$result->num_rows` en realidad estarías haciendo esto `false->num_rows` por ello te sale el error

Comment: el error del que hablas, en todo caso dice  algo asi `expects parameter 1 to be mysqli boolean given`

Comment: `mysqli_connect` tiene 4 parametros ... el host en tu caso es *localhost* ... luego el usuario en tu caso es *root* y el password en tu caso no tiene por ello hacen *""* el cuarto es la base de datos lo cual no especificaste ... Solo con los 3 primeros son suficiente para hacer una coneccion pero cuando haces la consulta `SELECT * FROM mensajes` Mysql no hace a que base de datos hacerle por ello falla mira este ejemplo [mysqli.connect](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php#refsect1-function.mysqli-connect-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Eso pasa cuando hay error en la consulta, me explico la columna del WHERE esta mal escrita verifica. ya que si solo no existiera el registro devuelve cero.

ejemplo

en la base de datos test, tabla users, columna email

```
SELECT * FROM test.users WHERE correo=""
```

Aqui dara ese error ya que la columna correo no existe debe ser corregida por email

Comment: El error que presenta OP no es de columna ya que si lo fuera presentaría el error **Unknown column '......'** cuando se utiliza una que no existe o esta mal escrita que no es el caso.